# Finding the intersection points of ray-5th order polynomial

Tags: matlab, geometry, intersection, raytracing

I am doing ray tracing and I have A screen described in the world coordinates as Matrices(I had before the X,Y,Z in the screen coordinates and by using transformation and rotation I got it in the world coordinates)

Xw (NXM Matrix)
Yw (NXM Matrix)
Zw (I have got this polynomial (5th order polynomial)by fitting the 3D data Xw and Yw. I have it as f(Xw,Yw))

I have the rays equations too described as usual:

```
X = Ox + t*Dx
Y = Oy + t*Dy
Z = Oz + t*Dz  %(O is the origin point and D is the direction)
```

So what I did is that I replaced the X and Y in the Polynomial equation f(Xw,Yw) and solved it for t so I can then get the intersection point.

But apparently the method that I used is wrong(The intersection points that I got were somewhere else).

Could any one please help me and tell me what is the mistake. Please support me.

Thanks

This is part of the code:

```
X_World_coordinate_scr = ScreenXCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(1,1) +    ScreenYCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(1,2) + ScreenZCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(1,3) + Zerobase_scr(1);
Y_World_coordinate_scr = ScreenXCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(2,1) + ScreenYCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(2,2) + ScreenZCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(2,3) + Zerobase_scr(2);
Z_World_coordinate_scr = ScreenXCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(3,1) + ScreenYCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(3,2) + ScreenZCoordinates.*Rotation_matrix_screen(3,3) + Zerobase_scr(3); % converting the screen coordinates to the world coordinates using the rotation matrix and the translation vector

polymodel = polyfitn([X_World_coordinate_scr(:),Y_World_coordinate_scr(:)],Z_World_coordinate_scr(:),5); % using a function from the MAtlab file exchange and I trust this function. I tried it different data and it gives me the f(Xw,Yw).
ScreenPoly = polyn2sym(polymodel); % Function from Matlab file exchange to give the symbolic shape of the polynomial.



syms X Y Z t Dx Ox Dy Oy oz Dz z;

tsun = matlabFunction(LayerPoly, 'vars',[X,Y,Z]); % just to substitue the symboles from X , Y  and Z to (Ox+t*Dx) , (Oy+t*Dy) and (Oz+t*Dz) respectively 
Equation = tsun((Ox+t*Dx),(Oy+t*Dy),(Oz+t*Dz));


Answer = solve(Equation,t); % solving it for t but the equation that it is from the 5th order and the answer is RootOf(.... for z)
a = char(Answer); % preparing it to find the roots (Solutions of t)
R = strrep(a,'RootOf(','');
R1 = strrep(R,', z)','');
b = sym(R1);
PolyCoeffs = coeffs(b,z); % get the coefficient of the polynomail

tfun = matlabFunction(PolyCoeffs, 'vars',[Ox,Oy,oz,Dx,Dy,Dz]);


tCounter = zeros(length(Directions),1);
NaNIndices = find(isnan(Surface(:,1))==1); %I have NaN values and I am taking them out  
tCounter(NaNIndices) = NaN;

NotNaNIndices = find(isnan(Surface(:,1))==0);

 for i = NotNaNIndices' % for loop to calc

 OxNew = Surface(i,1);
 OyNew = Surface(i,2);
 OzNew = Surface(i,3);

 DxNew = Directions(i,1);
 DyNew = Directions(i,2);
 DzNew = Directions(i,3);

 P = tfun(OxNew,OyNew,OzNew ,DxNew,DyNew,DzNew);

 t = roots(P);
 t(imag(t) ~= 0) = []; % getting rid of the complex solutions
 tCounter(i) = t;
 end
```

Please support

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reading this question I feel it is unclear what is meant by "the method that I used is wrong", especially what was the method? Also I guess the code doesn't run by itself. Anyway the question is already quite old. Is it already solved?